# How to load Hibernate/JPA object outside of a transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am migrating a web app from JDO to JPA. Previously I had one session for the life the request, but I only began a transaction when I needed to do updates.

Perhaps I am missing the obvious, but I can't see a way to do this with Hibernate/JPA.

My desired application flow looks something like this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();    
....
Foo f = session.get(Foo.class, fookey);    
....   
if(updateDesired)
{
   session.beginTransaction();
   f.setField(value);
   session.getTransaction().commit();
   ....
   Foo b = session.get(Foo.class, fookey);  // should be what was just written to db.
}

session.close();
```

Is this possible with Hibernate JPA?

I have tried to have a transaction opened at the beginning of the request, and committed at the end, but many of the assumptions my code makes are rendered invalid by that approach.

Comment: Why do you need to load the entity before you know you need to update it?

Comment: I load menus, based on the user logged, in from the database. Some screens display other data drawn from the database. There are many reasons for reading with out any intention of writing to the database.

Comment: Ok. Can you do everything (loading and updating) in a simple transaction? If not, why not, i.e. what are these assumptions your code makes?

Comment: Those dots elide hundreds of lines of code.  After the commit i read some of the objects back out of the database. With JPA, they aren't there yet.